# Mutiples click en formulario laravel

Tags: laravel

como evitar los envíos masivos de un click en un formulario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Probé con Jquery y funciona, pero deseo una alternativa más aceptable.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(':submit').click(function() {
        $(':submit').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.formulario').submit();
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Es perfectamente aceptable desactivar el botón. Adicionalmente puedes agregar un mensaje "enviando..." o un gráfico como una ruedita girando o algo asi para que el usuario se entere de qué está sucediendo

Comment: claro esto seria del lado del cliente, alguna idea de como hacerlo del lado del servidor.

Comment: Ah, ok. Una idea que se me ocurre es: Establecer un token único cuando entregues el formulario y guardarlo en la sesión, y al cliente pasárselo en un input oculto. Cuando recibes el formulario de vuelta, verificas el token, y si es válido lo borras y procesas el formulario. O si al recibir el formulario de vuelta, el token de la sesión no está (por fué borrado la primera vez), es un duplicado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función en tu script prinmcipal con jQuery por ejemplo que evite que se envié mas de una vez

```
// jQuery plugin to prevent double submission of forms
    jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function () {
        $(this).on('submit', function (e) {
            var $form = $(this);

            if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
                // Previously submitted - don't submit again
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                // Mark it so that the next submit can be ignored
                $form.data('submitted', true);
            }
        });

        // Keep chainability
        return this;
    };
```

Y luego simplemente usarla cuando la necesites.

```
            $('form').preventDoubleSubmission();
```